# How to get all of the HLS variants in a master manifest from a AVAsset or AVPlayerItem?

Tags: ios, avfoundation, tvos, http-live-streaming

Given an HLS manifest with multiple variants/renditions:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=1612430,CODECS="avc1.4d0020,mp4a.40.5",RESOLUTION=640x360
a.m3u8
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=3541136,CODECS="avc1.4d0020,mp4a.40.5",RESOLUTION=960x540
b.m3u8
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=5086455,CODECS="avc1.640029,mp4a.40.5",RESOLUTION=1280x720
c.m3u8
```

Is it possible to get an array of the three variants (with the attributes such as bandwidth and resolution) from either the AVAsset or AVPlayerItem?

I am able to get the currently playing AVPlayerItemTrack by using KVO on the AVPlayerItem, but again, it's only the track that's actively being played not the full list of variants.

I'm interested in knowing if the asset is being played at it's highest possible quality, so that I can make a decision on whether the user has enough bandwidth to start a simultaneous secondary video stream.

Comment: Have you checked the `AVAsset.trackGroups` property? From the documentation it sounds like it might match up.

Comment: @DaveWeston Yup, I've tried checking both the tracks and the trackGroups, but they always come back as an empty array, even when using `loadValuesAsynchronously` :/

Comment: Hey, Have you got the solution?, if yes please post in answer

Answer (score 1):

To know which variant you are currently playing, you can keep a KVO on AVPlayerItemNewAccessLogEntryNotification and by looking at AVPlayerItemAcessLogEvent in the access log, you can tell current bitrate and any change in bitrate.

```
AVPlayerItemAccessLog *accessLog = [((AVPlayerItem *)notif.object) accessLog];
AVPlayerItemAccessLogEvent *lastEvent = accessLog.events.lastObject;
if( lastEvent.indicatedBitrate != self.previousBitrate )
{
   self.bitrate = lastEvent.indicatedBitrate
}
```

As far as knowing the entire list of available bitrates, you can simply make a GET request for the master m3u8 playlist and parse it. You will only need to do it once so not much of an overhead.

Answer (score 0):

New in iOS 15, there’s AVAssetVariant